# Button not click behind Navigationbar in swift 3

Tags: swift, button, swift3, xcode8, navigationbar

I use a button over a view behind the navigation bar by code and unselect the property UnderTopBars in storyboard due to which I have set the y coordinate = -45.when my navigation bar slide above than the button show up but its not clickable .Not fire the touchup inside method

my code is

```
  searchBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.searchAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

func searchAction(_: UIButton) {

   print("Button Tapped")
}
```

my button look like after hide the navigation Bar

[image]

Comment: are you adding your search bar in Navigation Bar or behind it ?

Comment: try with  `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)`

Comment: @CodeChanger, its just named search bar but actually its button which not added to navigation Bar . Its behind the navigation Bar

Comment: @Salman Ghumsani , where to use this method

Comment: You can use it in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @– Salman Ghumsani , Its not working . Thanks for the comment

Comment: so You want navigation bar & button both ? and on same place ?

Comment: Yes , after hide the navigation bar than Button shows up

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can use **debug view hierarchy** for if any view is on top of your button on not???

and also make sure your button is enabled.